# Finding 9 characters before a particular string in Python

Tags: python, text-search

For example here I have a line '2020-08-12  13:45:04    0.86393 %contrastWeber' and I need to extract 9 characters before ' %contrastWeber' string in text file.
So, here my answer will be '0.86393'. I don't understand how to do it in Python? please help

[image: 1]

Comment: Please do not post images of text.

Comment: Why not just use a simple regex search: `"(.{9})%contrastWeber"`

Comment: Welcome! Give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a read for detail on asking questions. For more help here, I suggest you update your answer with text output of the above image, things you've tried, researched, and ultimately, a little more detail.

Comment: Convert the string to list using ```str.split(" ")``` and then find index of ```%contrastWeber``` in list. Then the text you want shall be at index 1 less than previous index you found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
line = '2020-08-12 13:45:04 0.86393 %contrastWeber'

position = line.index('%contrastWeber')

if position >= 0:
    starting = position - 9
    if starting < 0:
        starting = 0
    ending = position
    print(line[starting : ending])
else:
    print('is not found')
```